# Datagrid insert/adds new row everytime I click my Save button

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

i have a button (save) that everytime i click it, my datagrid adds new row so i have to click again and this time to save records from my datagrid.
is it because on my code behind i have this:

```
    private void uxItemBatchDetails_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (uxItemBatchDetails.Items.CurrentPosition == (uxItemBatchDetails.Items.Count - 1))
            (this.DataContext as ItemBatchViewModel).NewRow();
    }
```

the method NewRow() simply inserts a another row on my datagrid:

```
public void NewRow()
    {
        int rowIndex = 1;

        if (ItemBatchDetails.Count > 0)
            rowIndex = ItemBatchDetails.Max(i => i.RowIndex + 1);

        ItemBatchDetails.Insert(ItemBatchDetails.Count, new ItemBatchDetailViewModel(rowIndex));
    }
```

and for my XAML:

```
<Button Content="SAVE"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Width="80"
                        Background="#FF930936"
                        Foreground="White"
                        Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
```

am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality easily by binding your grid to the ObservableCollection in the ViewModel, and then adding item to the ObservableCollection (you will have to take an Add row button for that)! rather than trying to add row in the code behind NewRow method.

So do this: 
1. Bind your view to a ViewModel (setting View's datacontext to be the ViewModel)
2. Take an ObservableCollection the ViewModel (this is going to be your List, i. e. actual data)
3. In Add row button command handler, add an empty item to the datagrid.
4. now user can enter some records in new row.
5. In your save button simply save the ObservableCollection data to where ever you want to save this.

P.S. you can achieve this without taking Add New Row button also, but that is little trickier.